# Importing latitude and longitude data for UK

Tags: qgis, latitude-longitude

##### Data

I have a set of locations for weather stations (download easily from here: https://archive.ceda.ac.uk/cgi-bin/midas_stations/search_by_county.cgi.py?county=SHROPSHIRE&minyear=&maxyear=).

##### Problem

I want to plot them in QGIS, but when I import as CSV file, it places them in the completely wrong places. They are all in Shropshire, yet they are very far from Shropshire.

[image]

##### How I load the data

Project projection: EPSG:27700

[image]

Comment: Try the EPSG 27700 instead

Comment: try 4326 as they are lat/lon not OSGB - currently they are at the British Null Island (part of the Scilly Isles)

Comment: I'm sure your CSV file contains WGS84 coordinates, but you choose CRS 27700.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The coordinates from the archive of weather stations are in WGS 84 project system. Try choosing this for your project (EPSG:4326).

The CEDA web site tells you this if you look further, for example ACTON BURNELL has ~ https://archive.ceda.ac.uk/cgi-bin/midas_stations/station_details.cgi.py?id=9923&db=midas_stations